# Does the uniqueness of solutions to convex optimization with linear constraints hold in n>3 dimensions?

Tags: geometry, optimization, surfaces, nonlinear-optimization

This is a repost of an earlier question, where I think I was not clear enough in what I was asking:

I am examining the following optimization problem, for which I would like to know if, when a solution exists, is it unique?

Let $\mathcal{P}_{I}$ be a (known) partition of the set $I := \bigcup\limits_{1}^{N}[a_{i},b_{i}]\in \mathbb{R}$. For each element $p \in \mathcal{P}_{I}$ we are going to assign a quantity $y_{p} \in [0,1]$. Let $\lambda(\centerdot)$ be the Lebesgue measure.

The optimization problem is:

$\min \sum\limits_{p \in \mathcal{P}_{I}} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}(p)+y^{2}_{p}}$

s.t.

$\sum\limits_{p \in \mathcal{P}_{I}}g_{k}(p)L_{k}(y_{p}) = c_{k}, k \in \{1,2....M\}$

Where:
$g_{k}(p)$ is a function of the fixed partition only, while $L_{k}(y_{p})$ is a linear function of the decision variables $y_{i}$

**My thinking thus far:**

The objective function is strictly concave in $y_{i}$ for any fixed value of the objective function. Geometrically, for any fixed value of the objective function, the function represents a concave right-bounding surface in a high-dimensional vector space (i.e, one dimension per $y_{i}$) that is constrained in the positive region $[0,1]^{n}$.

However, the constraints define a piecewise-planar subspace in $[0,1]^{n}$ Therefore, as we decrease the value of the objective function, it seems that we will gradually get to the point where the feasible set for a given value of the objective function is either a corner-point of the feasbile set or a point of tangency to the surface of the objective function.

Since the objective function is strictly concave, I think I can make the following conclusion:

If the feasbile set consists of more than one point for a given value, K, of the objective function, then there exists a value $L<K$ of the objective function that also has a non-empty feasible set.

This follows from the fact that the dimension of the piecewise-planar feasible region for a given objective function value is always less than the dimension of the objective function. Essentially, I am resting on the analogy of a cutting plane: you cannot cut a strictly concave surface with a plane such that the intersection set has more than one point and the entire concave surface lies at or completely below the plane.

Sorry for the long-winded post, but I wanted to lay out my thinking. I think the above shows that if a minimum exists, the minimium is unique. I also think this extends to infinite-dimensional vector spaces as the norm of the partition approaches zero.

*Does this reasoning make sense? Does the intuition of convex optimzation with linear constraints for n $\leq$ 3 dimensions hold for higher dimensions (possibly infinite?)*

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this question too wordy or elementary? I've posted twice with not one comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've done a bit of reading and found that this is indeed true in both the finite and infinite spaces. The following [reference from UCLA](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam04-11.pdf) shows that the defining property of convex minimization problems is that if a local minimum is found, it is also a global mimimum. Here, the functional equality contraints are affine in y and the surface of the objective function is convex, so this is a convex optimization in a vector space and hence has a unique global solution.