# Are solutions to optimization problems with smooth, continuous, and strictly concave objective functions and linear constraints always unique?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

As an example, if I have a minimzation problem where my objective function is represented by a sphere in n dimensions (one dimension per decision variable), and all my constraints are linear, then does a unique solution always exist? If not, what conditions are required on the constraints for this to be the case?

I am particularly interested in situations where all the constraints are linear equalities.

Comment: A strictly convex function on a convex domain has a unique minimum (unless it is unbounded below). A strictly concave function on a convex domain has a unique maximum (unless it is unbounded above). See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization

Comment: However, a *concave* function may not have a unique *minimum*, for example $\min -x^2$ for $-1\le x\le 1$.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks for the input. Would a minimzation problem using a spherical objective function in 3 dimensions subject to linear equality constraints qualify as convex objective with convex domain?

Comment: Linear constraints (whether equality or inequality) are always convex. I don't know what a spherical objective function is. If you mean something like $x^2+y^2+z^2$, then yes.

Comment: @RahulNarain yes, that was what I meant. Thank you! That answered my question.

Comment: @RahulNarain on a related note: Does the above statement in 3 dimensions generalize to n>3 dimensions, including function spaces (where the objective function becomes the integral: $\int f(x)^2 dx$ with linear integral constraints on f(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> objective function is represented by a sphere

Writing $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ (since it turned out to be what you meant) would be a lot more clear.

Since the function $f$ is strictly convex, it has unique point of minimum on a any convex  set; in particular, on a set defined by linear constraints. (As Rahul Narain already said in comments).

Comment: I didn't mean only that function, its just a representative example of the types of optimiation surfaces I am dealing with. They exhibit a constant sense of the curvature. As I asked Rahul, does this property of convex functions extend to the infinite dimensional case, where the objective function is a convex *functional* and the constraints are linear functionals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meant convex objective function, but in either case, the solution is not guaranteed to be unique.

Example: $\min_{\mathbb{R}^2} 0, \: x_1 = 0$

Comment: What if there are linear equality constraints only?

Comment: Noted, thanks...

Comment: I've slightly edited my question..note the word "strictly concave". Are there any non-trivial examples? Using your above example, we could almost disprove uniqueness of ordinary linear differential equations as well.

Comment: Ross, thanks for your replies. You are helping me refine my question as we speak. I am thinking of an objective function that is smooth-continuous and has strict concavity in n dimensions. The constraints will be N-1 dimesional linear surfaces of equality.

Comment: a counter example to my question might also be: $max\space x^2+y^2\space st.\space x-y=0$ this goes through the origin, so its satistifed for all values of the radius. However, its minimziatoin problem has a unique solution (0,0)

Comment: Hmm, with the added information it intuitively seems correct, though I can't articulate it mathematically at the moment.

Comment: Yeah..that's my feeling too. I tried a more abstract appraoch here, but I don't know if it got me very far: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530960/does-the-uniqueness-of-solutions-to-convex-optimization-with-linear-constraints